# How can I retrieve all commits that changed files with one or two kinds of extensions?

Tags: git, msr

How can I retrieve all commits that changed files with one or two kinds of extensions, e.g. ".YAML" and ".JSON"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git log --no-merges --oneline --name-status -- :*.yaml :*.json
```

with `--oneline` and `--name-status` basically being eye candy here.

The reason for the `--no-merges` is, a merge is of all the changes in the merged histories, so all the files that changed in that merge *from either parent* count. But since you're not restricting the walkback, you're going to see the commits that originally made those changes anyway (and `git log` knows this, and generally doesn't show diffs for merge commits anyway as that gets repetitive and increasingly worse-than-useless as histories get larger).

`--first-parent` rather than `--no-merges` with selected paths tells you which files were changed relative only to the first parent by the (no longer excluded) merges; rather than showing you the individual merged commits that changed those files it shows you the merges that brought those changes into the first-parent history you've got checked out.

`git log` with paths and neither `--first-parent` nor `--no-merges` turns out to be useful only as a forensics kind of query.

Comment: This colon in your git command seems extremely useful. What's its meaning?

Comment: @zkoza It's the marker for git's "pathspec" special syntax, say `git help glossary` and hunt it up. You can ask it to check specific `.gitattributes`, for instance, and only use the paths marked the way you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've read the documentation and made some experiments. Wouldn't    `:/*.yaml :/*.json` work better?

Comment: @zkoza depends on what you want. The leading slash anchors the path at the work tree root, so use it if those are the only yaml/json files you're interested in.

Comment: But isn't it what OP is asking for? The slash makes the search find all yaml and json files at the git project root directory **and below** regardless of the directory the search was made from. Without it the search returns the values from the current directory and below. Just a remark, perhaps of no actual relevance.

Comment: @zkoza you're right about the `*` matching any path sequence but I don't see where op asked to shut off implicit current-directory-and-below searching.